# Creating topics, but getting Kafka FailedPayloadsError with Python on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kubernetes, kafka-python

I'm using a SimpleProducer in the python kafka-library.
This script has worked flawlessly previously with other more hard-configured kafka-setups I've tried.

```
kafka = KafkaClient(u'[masterNodeIp]:[servicePort]')
producer = SimpleProducer(kafka)
#make a simple message, while true run
producer.send_messages(b'oneMoreTopic', sentence)
```

After running this script once, I get this response in the python-console.

```
kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableError: TopicMetadata(topic='oneMoreTopic', error=5, partitions=[])
```

I can then go into my Node on my zookeeper.log and see:

```
2015-09-14 12:16:32,276 - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:3  cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@627] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x34fcb982d030000 type:setData cxid:0x71 zxid:0x1000000d8 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/topics/oneMoreTopic Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /config/topics/oneMoreTopic
2015-09-14 12:16:32,278 - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:3 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@627] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x34fcb982d030000 type:create cxid:0x72 zxid:0x1000000d9 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/topics Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /config/topics
2015-09-14 12:16:32,302 - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:3 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@627] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x34fcb982d030000 type:create cxid:0x7b zxid:0x1000000dc txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/topics/oneMoreTopic/partitions/0 Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/oneMoreTopic/partitions/0
2015-09-14 12:16:32,304 - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:3 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@627] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x34fcb982d030000 type:create cxid:0x7c zxid:0x1000000dd txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/topics/oneMoreTopic/partitions Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/oneMoreTopic/partitions
```

This seems to just be the Zookeeper creating a new Znode for the topic since it is not there from before. And the Kafka server.log prints:

```
[2015-09-14 12:16:32,282] INFO Topic creation {"version":1,"partitions":{"0":[10200119]}} (kafka.admin.AdminUtils$)
[2015-09-14 12:16:32,287] INFO [KafkaApi-10200219] Auto creation of topic oneMoreTopic with 1 partitions and replication factor 1 is successful! (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
[2015-09-14 12:16:51,579] INFO Closing socket connection to /10.240.1.94. (kafka.network.Processor)
```

However, my message is never posted to the topic and the next time i run the python-script i always get:

```
kafka.common.FailedPayloadsError
```

In the cases where i made it work, the advertised.host.name was always the external IP of the node, but I can't seem to get that working through Kubernetes. Would it be possible to make the external IP callable from the container parhaps?

my kafka/config/server.properties looks something like this for all brokers:

```
broker.id=10200121
host.name=kafka-f8p06
advertised.host.name=kafka-f8p06
++
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of my problem was fixed by making sure all my nodes could reach the internet by doing

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -d 10.0.0.0/8 -o ens4v1 -j MASQUERADE
```

After this, I changed the advertised.host.name to the external IP address I'm trying to reach my broker from. So if my GCE-node is located on 156.99.33.101, with a nodePort open on 33777 for my kafka-service, I would put:

```
advertised.host.name=156.99.33.101
advertised.host.port=33777
```

The advertised.host.name is what kafka uses to connect back to itself when one of the brokers get a request, so using the external address at least makes it reachable. Although I'm not sure if there are any consequenses to directing it outside the local address-space.

[Topic about LeaderNotAvailableException remotely](http://users.kafka.apache.narkive.com/PFbfIGcY/quickstart-ok-locally-but-getting-warn-property-topic-is-not-valid-and-leadernotavailableexception)

Answer (score 1):

```
broker.id=10200121
host.name=kafka-f8p06  <----- use IP here
advertised.host.name=kafka-f8p06  <---- use IP here
```

I think you should have IPs for `host.name` and `advertised.host.name` as K8s does not resolve Pods by hostname but it does by IP.

Your kafka nodes probably can't talk to each other that way and can't find the leader.